# javabridge installation errors

Tags: java, python, installation

I'm using Python 3.7 on a Mac, for context.

Attempting to install using pip results in the following error:

```
Collecting javabridge
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a6/a0/c59bccabed99b1d4ac68166c59c679b375bfca75b78688b52c541b711578/javabridge-1.0.18.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Could not find Java JRE compatible with x86_64 architecture
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/04/76dktb_j6hj2qq9tx78jrzyc0000gp/T/pip-install-ha92_2b7/javabridge/setup.py", line 402, in <module>
        ext_modules=ext_modules(),
      File "/private/var/folders/04/76dktb_j6hj2qq9tx78jrzyc0000gp/T/pip-install-ha92_2b7/javabridge/setup.py", line 95, in ext_modules
        raise Exception("JVM not found")
    Exception: JVM not found

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/04/76dktb_j6hj2qq9tx78jrzyc0000gp/T/pip-install-ha92_2b7/javabridge/
```

I've uninstalled and reinstalled JDK and Java (also tried downgrading, upgrading, everything else I can think of) after reading other similar questions, so I'm not sure what else to try.